# Spring security login form jsessionid not sent accros domains

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, pivotal-web-services

I have two Spring boot applications one is a client UI app and the other acts as an Authorization Server (using spring security oauth, implicit flow and form login).

When the two applications run on localhost (different ports) I can see the following flow:

The client makes a request to oauth/ahthorize to retrieve a token.
Since the client is not authenticated the server responds with a 302 redirect to its login form, setting also two cookies (XSRF, JSESSIONID).

The user enters his credentials and a POST is performed in the login form. Since the two apps run in localhost the two Cookies are sent in the POST request.

This way, the server retrieves the SavedRequest for this JSESSIONID and performs a redirect to the saved client url, as expected.

The problem is when running the two applications in different domains (I am trying to run it in Pivotal Web services environment).

The JSESSIONID cookie is not sent on POST of the login form.

This makes sense because the cookie was set for the client domain, whereas the login form is in a different domain and does not have access to the cookie.

This has as a result that the server does not find a SavedRequest object to retrieve the redirect URL
of the client and it redirects to the root of the server (/)

What am I missing?

EDIT: here is the POST on the login page on localhost (working scenario):
[image]

and here is the POST when domains are different (not working):
[image]

EDIT 2: Here is the authorize request, which is made to the client domain (and proxied to the server through Zuul:
[image]

Comment: The session is only needed for authorizaion server. You get the login page with CSRF token and session id from authorization server. You post the username and password to authorization server with session id and CSRF token. Then the authorization server returns a redirect (302) with the configured redirect URL. That URL is on client-side and doesn't need the CSRF token and session id from authorization server.

Comment: @alex: *The JSESSIONID cookie is not sent on POST of the login form.* That is not possible. The login page and the login processing URL are on authorization server, so the cookie must be send. Could you add the HTTP `POST` request to your question (for example a screenshot of your dev tool in your browser)?

Comment: @dur as I said, it works when domain of client and server is the same. does not work when client and server are in different domains

Comment: @dur your last comment made me realised that I have ommited an important detail from the implementation. The client application communicates with the server through a Zuul proxy. So the client app does not call directly the server_domain/oauth/authorize. It calls the client_domain?oauth/authorize and Zuul is responsible to forward the request to server_domain/oauth/authorize. This is the reason the cookie is stored for the client domain. Sorry for waisting your time. Still I think this is a common scenario and I am missing something
I also added a screenshot of the authorize request

Comment: @alex: Okay, the problem is the "forward" to the server domain, which results in a redirect to the server domain. The client sees only a redirect from client domain to server domain, the "forward" is hidden for the client.

Comment: One solution is to change the proxy to make a "redirect".  Another way would be to change the redirect to use the client domain. With Apache proxy it is no problem, I always get the redirects to the proxy domain.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean that the proxy should redirect the client to server_path/oauth/authorize? If that's it, is it a good practice? This means that the client must have access to the authorization server directly. Also it adds an extra round-trip

Comment: No, it is not a good  solution, but the client must have access to the authorization server anyway, because the authorization server sends a redirect to login page (and as you can see in your screenshot, it is not the proxy URL). Better solution is to configure the proxy to not return redirect to the server domain, but only to the proxy (client domain).

Comment: @dur thanks for your feedback. you are right about the login redirect. not sure if what you describe is possible with zuul but I will give it a try

Comment: @dur after A LOT of debugging I managed to do as you said (rewrite Location headers of redirects to point to the proxy domain). So now the JESSIONID is passed correctly. The problem now is that the authorization server sees the POST in the login form as a cross-origin request (since the Origin header points to the client domain) and fails since the client domain is not in the list of allowed domains. Considering that many clients might be using the same authorization server what is a good practice in this case? allow all cross origin requests?

Comment: No, it is not good practice, but I don't know any other solution.